# Raspberry pi GPIO sysfs, fopen: Permission denied

Tags: c, raspberry-pi, fopen, gpio, sysfs

I'm trying to use raspberry pi GPIOs through sysfs using the C language, but I keep getting `fopen: Permission denied` when trying to change the GPIO line direction.
The issue occurs when trying to open the file `"/sys/class/gpio/gpio18/direction"`.

Notes:

- If I run the program for a second time it works fine.
- If I export the GPIO line manually and then execute it works fine.
- If I run the program as root it works fine.
- My current user is part of the gpio group and should have all permissions.

Normally I would need to put the pin that I want to use in `"/sys/class/gpio/export"`.
And then I need to set its direction (output/input) by writing `1` or `0` to `"/sys/class/gpio/gpio18/direction"`.

To achieve that programmatically I use the following code

```c
#include "io.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char const* argv[]) {
  // export line
  FILE* p_gpio_line;
  if ((p_gpio_line = fopen("/sys/class/gpio/export", "w")) == NULL) {
    printf("Cannot open export file.\n");
    perror("fopen");
    exit(1);
  }
  rewind(p_gpio_line);
  fwrite("18", sizeof(char), 2, p_gpio_line);
  fclose(p_gpio_line);

  // set direction
  FILE* p_gpio_direction;
  if ((p_gpio_direction = fopen("/sys/class/gpio/gpio18/direction", "r+")) == NULL) {
    printf("Cannot open direction file.\n");
    perror("fopen");
    exit(1);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

The first time it executes I get

```
Cannot open direction file.
fopen: Permission denied
```

The second time it works fine because the GPIO line is exported before the program is executed (from the first execution)
It also works fine if I manually export the GPIO line from the terminal

[image: terminal output]

Comment: Don't use `perror()` unless right after failed function. `printf()` may change `errno` so `perror()` message makes no sense.

Comment: Use `libgpiod` and its resources, do not use sysfs for GPIO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My comment about `perror()` remains in effect, but indeed in your example `fopen()` returns EACCES ("Permission denied").

Group `gpio` and permissions for `/sys/class/gpio` are specific for Raspberry Pi distro. They are set by udev rule in `/etc/udev/rules.d/99-com.rules`:

```
SUBSYSTEM=="gpio", ACTION=="add", PROGRAM="/bin/sh -c 'chgrp -R gpio /sys%p && chmod -R g=u /sys%p'"
```

Udev rule is applied asynchronously after `direction` file appears. You are trying to open the file while permissions aren't yet set.

I'd suggest to use character device GPIO interface with [libgpiod](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/libs/libgpiod/libgpiod.git) instead of deprecated sysfs interface.

If you still want to use sysfs interface, straightforward solution is to retry `fopen()` until it succeed (or fail with error other than EACCES, or timeout). For example:

```c
// Open timeout, ms
#define DIR_OPEN_TIMEOUT_MS 3000
// Delay between retries, ms
#define DIR_POLL_DELAY_MS   100

...
    // set direction
    FILE* p_gpio_direction;
    unsigned int retries_left = DIR_OPEN_TIMEOUT_MS / DIR_POLL_DELAY_MS;
    while (1)
    {
        p_gpio_direction = fopen("/sys/class/gpio/gpio18/direction", "r+");

        if (p_gpio_direction)
            break;

        if ((errno != EACCES) || (retries_left-- == 0)) {
            printf("Cannot open direction file: %m\n");
            exit(1);
        }

        const struct timespec rqt = {
            .tv_sec  = DIR_POLL_DELAY_MS / 1000,
            .tv_nsec = 1000000L * (DIR_POLL_DELAY_MS % 1000)
        };
        if (nanosleep(&rqt, NULL) == -1)
            perror("nanosleep()");
    }
...
```

Comment: That explains it thanks, one question tho if I wanted to still use sysfs how can I wait for the rule to apply before accessing the `direction` file?

Comment: This is not a good direction to solve the issue. We need to have `libgpiod` enabled for GPIO, sysfs must not be used.