# PI-OS GPIO direction interface failing after OS upgrade. Why?

Tags: gpio, tomcat9, udev, raspberry-pi-os

Servlet requires nonprivileged access. Tomcat was added to gpio group and udev rules applied. But after kernel update to `Linux pihive1 6.1.61+ #1696 Thu Nov  2 16:33:31 GMT 2023 armv6l GNU/Linux` on

```
Raspberry Pi Details:
  Type: Pi Zero-W, Revision: 01, Memory: 512MB, Maker: Sony 
  * Device tree is enabled.
  *--> Raspberry Pi Zero W Rev 1.1
  * This Raspberry Pi supports user-level GPIO access.
```

servlet reports exception:

```
Nov 17 14:17:57 pihive1 tomcat9[484]: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to open GPIO direction interface for pin [22]: Permission denied
Nov 17 14:17:57 pihive1 tomcat9[484]:         at com.pi4j.wiringpi.GpioUtil.export(Native Method)
Nov 17 14:17:57 pihive1 tomcat9[484]:         at com.pi4j.io.gpio.WiringPiGpioProviderBase.export(WiringPiGpioProviderBase.java:108)
```

Adapting /etc/udev/rules.d/99-com.rule by adding /dev/gpiomem

```
$ diff backup-99-com.rules /etc/udev/rules.d/99-com.rules
10c10,11
<       chown -R root:gpio /sys$devpath && chmod -R 770 /sys$devpath\
---
>       chown -R root:gpio /sys$devpath && chmod -R 770 /sys$devpath;\
>         chown root:gpio /dev/gpiomem && chmod g+rw /dev/gpiomem\
```

solved the problem, but assumption was that pi4j uses same deprecated sysfs approach as python gpio lib.
Did I miss something?

Note: the "first try fails" - topic mentioned in [Raspberry pi GPIO sysfs, fopen: Permission denied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76138933/raspberry-pi-gpio-sysfs-fopen-permission-denied)
persists but is acceptable.

Comment: Don’t use non standard interfaces for GPIO, kernel provides the character device, and there is `libgpiod` in case one doesn’t want to reinvent a wheel.